Help with Connector
I just found this site and was hoping someone can help me out.  I'm looking for the empty connector in the pics.  This is for a Ford truck 3rd brake light.




Oh boy. That's an automotive connector. They are a challenge.
Ask these guys: https://connectorexperts.com/ or these guys: https://www.automotiveconnectors.com/ or these guys: https://findpigtails.com/
Or, go to the parts department for the dealer for that brand of vehicle and they'll sell you a connector with wire tails already in it.

Need dimensions for component identification questions
